# AngularJs ngClick Cache Update Issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am attempting to pass a value to JavaScript function when `ng-click` call. But its passing wrong value.

`ng-click="removeObj(det, '{{$index+1}}')` here `index` is 0 so when i do inspect element in chrome its shows `ng-click="removeObj(det, '1')`

In JavaScript function: `self.removeObj = function(formObject, id)` -> here `id` is coming as 2 instead of 1.

**Sample.html**

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="det in sellingTable">
    <td data-title="S.No.">{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td data-title="Product">{{det.sellProduct}}</td>
    <td data-title="Plan">{{det.sellPlan}}</td>
    <td data-title="Amt">{{det.sellAmt}}</td>
    <td data-title="Action">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="removeObj(det, '{{$index+1}}')">
        Remove
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-if="sellingTable =='' || sellingTable ==null">
    <td colspan="5">No records found</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Please find below attached chrome inspect element file of my code

[image]

[image]

Comment: post your HTML code

Comment: @ Sajeetharan i have added my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directly pass *index*

```
<a ng-click="removeObj(det, $index+1)"
```

instead of *interpolating*

```
<a ng-click="removeObj(det, '{{$index+1}}')"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it out sans the braces. Here it goes :

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="det in sellingTable">
    <td data-title="S.No.">{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td data-title="Product">{{det.sellProduct}}</td>
    <td data-title="Plan">{{det.sellPlan}}</td>
    <td data-title="Amt">{{det.sellAmt}}</td>
    <td data-title="Action">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="removeObj(det, $index+1)">
        Remove
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-if="sellingTable =='' || sellingTable ==null">
    <td colspan="5">No records found</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Hope it works !

Comment: Anytime @deadend